# Full screen header with gradient for all screens including mobile phones from 1920 px to 420 px

Tags: html

I want to learn some basics in website development so that I can control the look and design of my site.

My website developer says that a full screen header with a  gradient left to right won't work because screen size differs from 1920 down to 420 for mobile phones. My  website is being optimised for browsing on mobile phones. Is there a way around this?

I have an image of what I am referring to. How do I post it for users to see here? (My website is a customised Magenta Go website.)

Comment: As a brand new user, OP hasn't earned the 10 reputation points needed to post images directly to StackOverflow. As an alternative, he can upload his image to a hosting site like Imageshack and put a link to the image in his post.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not extremely clear, but it's possible that what you're looking for are [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and "responsive design".

I really recommend looking at how Twitter Bootstrap is doing it: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Basically, you modify your CSS for different screen widths, possibly in your case providing different gradients for each case. And screen categories defined by Twitter Bootstrap in the aforementioned documentation seem pretty reasonable for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

A general way to get a horizontal gradient to work on both large screens and mobiles is using CSS gradients, [like this example](http://jsbin.com/ihexav). You can find an [indication of browsers that support CSS gradients](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients) on the [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) website.